# how to sort an array of files by keyword match of file name

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, dir

I have this sort function which scans a directory and lists all `jpg` files, how could I make it to sort only `jpg` files whose file-name match a specified keyword, for example to find and sort all `jpg` files whose name includes the keyword `"toys"`.

```
   $a_img[] = array(); // return values
$keyword = "toys"; // your keyword
$allowed_types = array('jpg'); // list of filetypes you want to show  
 $dimg = opendir($imgdir);  
 while($imgfile = readdir($dimg)) {
     // check to see if filename contains keyword
    if(false!==strpos($keyword, $imgfile)){
       //check file extension
        $extension = strtolower(substr($imgfile, strrpos($imgfile, ".")+1));
        if (in_array($extension, $allowed_types)) {
        // add file to your array
        $a_img[] = $imgfile;
        }
    }   
}
// sort alphabetically by filename
sort($a_img);


   $totimg = count($a_img); // total image number  
   for($x=0; $x < $totimg; $x++)  
       { 

    $size = getimagesize($imgdir.'/'.$a_img[$x]);  
   // do whatever  

   echo $a_img[$x];  

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to check the filename for occurrences of your keyword using `strpos()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php - and only add those files to your array. Assuming you want to sort alphabetically by filename, you sort this array using the `sort()` function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

When using `strpos()` make sure to test for `!==false` otherwise your keyword at the beginning of the filename (for example "toys_picture.jpg") will return `0`, which is falsey but not false.

You can also use `strrpos()` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php - to find the last occurrence of a `.` in your filename and use that for `substr()` should you want to support 3 and 4 character file extensions (both "jpg" and "jpeg" for example).

```
$imgdir = "idximages"; // directory
$keyword = "toys"; // your keyword
$allowed_types = array('jpg'); // list of filetypes you want to show  
$a_img = array(); // return values
$dimg = opendir($imgdir);  
while($imgfile = readdir($dimg)) {
    // check to see if filename contains keyword
    if(false!==strpos($imgfile, $keyword)){
        //check file extension
        $extension = strtolower(substr($imgfile, strrpos($imgfile, ".")+1));
        if (in_array($extension, $allowed_types)) {
            // add file to your array
            $a_img[] = $imgfile;
        }
    }   
}
// sort alphabetically by filename
sort($a_img);

// iterate through filenames
foreach ($a_img as $file){
    $imagesize = getimagesize($imgdir.'/'.$file);
    print_r($imagesize);
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = $imagesize;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I am totally flustered with arrays unfortunately, i just don't get it. but I tried adding your code to mine it didn't throw an error but it didn't return any results either. I have 13 images for each keyword so a set of images are named like toys.jpg, toysa.jpg, toysb.jpg, toysc.jpg, and another set of images might be named cars.jpg, carsa.jpg, carsb.jpg, etc... so I need to finda return all jpg files with the keyword toys in them.

Comment: Have you tried adding some `echo` lines to see where the code is breaking down?

Comment: @KarenBemusOsh - my bad, I had the parameters for `if(false!==strpos($imgfile, $keyword))` backwards, it should be `strpos($haystack, $needle)`. Please see my edits.

Comment: yes, I have an echo in it, but it just returns false and shows nothing. I'd like to paste my new code in here but I can't figure out where to paste it (yeah I'm totally ignorant lol)

Comment: ok I tried your edit code but now I'm getting the following error  Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: I pasted my new code in my original post, now it's putting the Array in the image directory path and returning the error Warning: getimagesize(idximages/Array) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: you need to make sure to define your array `$a_img[] = array();` - what is the value of `$imgdir`?

Comment: yes, I forgot to add the $a_img[] = array(); after I added it (see the code in my original post) it then returns the error Warning: getimagesize(idximages/Array) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory (notice it's calling the directory as idximages/Array

Comment: Sorry, I actually put the code into a file to test - you need `$a_img = array();`, if you use `$a_img[] = array();` then you are setting on of the array elements to another array. See updates and it should work.

Comment: Great, it would be appreciated if you could mark this as the answer now that everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strrpos` to check for a substring's existence in another string

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Look at the examples on that page and you should be able to match `toys` and exclude that from your array if it's not there

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I've missed something but after you've said "yes, it's a JPG" you'd do something like:

```
if(strstr($imgfile, 'toys'))
{
  //carry on
}
```